# Errors at declaration of enum

Tags: c++, enums

```
class API {
public:

        //States that the API can be in.
        enum API_STATE {
    /* Line 35*/ INITIAL = 0, OPENED = 1, READY = 2, STOPPED = 3, OPENFORXFER = 4
        };
```

I am getting errors at line 35. As follow. On include of the header file which have above code.

```
error: expected identifier before numeric constant
h:35: error: expected â}â before numeric constant
h:35: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

Comment: It builds for me. Have you provided the real code? http://ideone.com/VfvfEv

Comment: Are you sure you're using **only** ASCII symbols in your codes?

Comment: @Edward `â` is probably a quote character that's been mangled in copying.

Comment: `SHOUTY_CAPS` are often used for macros. Perhaps there's a macro defined somewhere that stomps over one of your shouty names. Consider using more lower case - it's easier on the eye, as well as less likely to clash with the preprocessor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a macro defining `INITIAL` (or possibly `OPENED` etc.) to a numeric literal:

```
#define INITIAL 0
enum API_STATE {
    INITIAL = 0, OPENED = 1, READY = 2, STOPPED = 3, OPENFORXFER = 4
};
```

Clang gives precisely the error you reported:

```
!!error: expected identifier before numeric constant
!!error: expected ‘}’ before numeric constant
!!error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
```

Comment: thanks ..there was INITIAL defined somewhere with value 1  in the code which was conflicting with this INITIAL